# Single Sign On With Azure AD with two URLs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, owin, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

Assume I have 2 urls pointing to one website, just use site binding, example:

```
productname1.company.com
productname2.company.com
```

Our web application does single sign on to Azure Active Directory, and in Azure Application Configuration, I have put:

```
productname1.company.com
```

for SIGN-ON URL and REPLY URL:

[image]

If user comes to `productname1.company.com`, the Azure single sign on authentication works perfectly.

But if user comes to `productname2.company.com`, it does not work at all and redirect to login page of `productname1.company.com`.

How do I configure to make it works with `productname2.company.com`, I am using OWIN OpenIdConnect to do single sign on with Azure AD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `productname2.company.com` as a second Reply URL, and then have your app specify the appropriate Reply URL when it redirects to AAD.

You can do this in the `RedirectToIdentityProvider` Notification within the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` used to configure OWIN OpenID Connect.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
   new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
   {
      Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
      {
         RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
           {
              // This ensures that the address used for sign in and sign out is picked up dynamically from the request
              // this allows you to deploy your app (to Azure Web Sites, for example) without having to change settings
              // Remember that the base URL of the address used here must be defined as a Redirect URI in Ping beforehand.
              string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
              string currentUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.Path;
              context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = currentUrl;
              context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
           }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Not sure why you are setting .PostLogoutRedirecteUri, but it shouldn't do any harm.

Comment: It's not needed for the login flow, but if you were implementing logout this is where you would specify it.